# Iterate over columns and plotting them using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ggplot2, graph

I have a numeric data frame call `A`, and I want to make a graph for every two variables (columns) of `A`.

My try:

```
x <- unlist(lapply(D, is.numeric))    
A <- D[,x]
for(i in (1:ncol(A)))
{
  for(j in (1:ncol(A)))
  {
    ggplot(algas, aes(x = A[,i], y = A[,j])) +
    geom_point() 
  }
}
```

But is not plotting anything. I'm not sure if it's necessary to save each plot in a vector and then plot them with another for. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
dat <- mtcars %>% select(c(1, 3:7))
combs <- combn(names(dat), 2) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
plots <- purrr::map2(combs$V1, combs$V2, ~ggplot(dat, aes_string(x=.x, y=.y)) + geom_point())
plots
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[4]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[5]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[6]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[7]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[8]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[9]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[10]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[11]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[12]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[13]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[14]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[15]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could also try `ggpairs()` from the `GGally` package:

```r
library(GGally)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'GGally':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- mtcars %>% select(c(1, 3:7))
ggpairs(dat)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, Dave! How would you do the combinations between ´´´A´´´ and another data frame (without considering the ones between themselves) ?